# Using RegEx to apply a scale factor to a JavaScript string variable

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string below called "embed"  where I want to modify the width parameter by the scale factor (.8 here).

```
scale = .8;
var embed = '<iframe width="960" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/kk5xfJodtrk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

So when I'm done the embed string should read:

```
embed = '<iframe width="768" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/kk5xfJodtrk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

Actually, width=768, without the quotes,  would also work for me.

I've tried a lot of things.  The latest is

```
var scale = .8;
var embed = '<iframe width="960" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/kk5xfK0ovrk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

var new_embed = embed.replace(/width="(\d+)/,"width=" + scale*$1);
```

But this complains that $1 is not defined.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can't do that, $1 is a substring in the regex engine

Comment: you ned to use a special anonymous function.

Comment: Try this `/width="?(\d+)"?/gi` demo. https://regex101.com/r/fG7uP7/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
//bit long, but works, can be shortened , no time :P
var scale = 0.5;

var embed = '<iframe width="960" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/kk5xfK0ovrk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

var embed = embed.replace(/width="(\d+)/,function myFunction(x){return "width=\""+x.replace("width=\"","") *scale;} );

var embed = embed.replace(/height="(\d+)/,function myFunction(y){return "height=\""+y.replace("height=\"","") *scale;} );


document.write(embed);
```

Comment: Thanks!  What worked for me is: var embed = embed.replace(/width="(\d+)/, function(x,y) { return "width=\"" + scale*y });

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regular expressions:

```
// create temporary element and parse HTML inside
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.innerHTML = embed;

// adjust width
d.firstChild.width *= 0.8;

// write into the document (or use appendChild)
document.write(d.innerHTML);
```